# Is Xively web socket down?

Tags: xively

Over last few days I've noticed Xively is no longer sending me push notifications over web socket - api.xively.com port 8080.  Can anyone confirm it is working for them or they also have the issue?  Xively are not responding to emails or tweets.

This worked for years and I have not changed my code.  Just finished debugging and can't see a problem my end.  This is the kind of error I see:

{"status":500,"headers":{"DATE":"Wed, 04 Nov 2015 12:08:36 GMT","CONTENT_TYPE":"application/json; charset=utf-8","CONTENT_LENGTH":"123","CONNECTION":"close","X_REQUEST_ID":"cfd15806f62691e9cd1837f3a0bbd77c64d2ccaf"},"body":{"title":"Oops, something's broken","errors":"We've been unable to complete your request due to a problem with our server"},"token":"0xabcdef","resource":"/feeds/28248241"}

Note I edited that feed ID above not be valid.
I have tried several valid feeds and data streams - all fail.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Perhaps you mail to someone there and ask?

Comment: I tried that and their twitter a few times - no joy.  It seems specific to their web sock push that isn't working.  I've since tried some other SDKs that used to work and they are also no longer working - it seems they have a problem with web socket although REST works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Went offline for me on 16th October 2015. Their twitter feed implied a transient problem, but I had no response from either a polite tweet or an email to the address they offered in reply to other personal users. Where next?